# How to move files to already existing folders based on which folder name is in each file name?

Tags: batch-file

I have many folders created already consisting of only (7) numeric characters.  The folders are located in the same parent directory as the files to move.  The filename format may contain one of the folder names at the beginning followed by either a space or underscore.  There possibly could be filenames which do not have a corresponding folder but do contain a 7-digit prefix, in which case a folder would need to be created before moving the file.  In this scenario, I would like to add a confirmation before continuing.  Filenames which have no spaces or underscores should remain.

I would like to move the files into the matching folder, i.e. file `3345513_sdfg_89.abc` would be moved into folder `3345513`. I was thinking for each folder name, for each file name that contains the folder name, move the file to the folder.

```
FOR /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /B /A-D "*.*"') DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%B IN ("%%A") DO (
        SET "token_1=%%B"
        SET "num_test=!token_1:~-1!"
        SET "foldername=!token_1!"
        MD "!foldername!\" >nul 2>&1
        MOVE "%%~fA" "!foldername!\"
    )
)
```

Above is the original code attempt, however,
looking for a simpler approach with confirmation added: What batch code could be used to simplify the above assuming the folder name format is comprised of (7) numeric characters?

Below is what I have since compiled thus far.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I IN ('dir "???????" /AD-H /B 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /X "......."') DO MOVE /Y "%%I*" "%%I" >nul 2>nul
:choice
set /P c=Files remain, create new folders for these files[Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :somewhere
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :somewhere_else
goto :choice
:somewhere
@For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1*Delims=_" %%A In ('Dir /B/A-D "*_*" 2^>NUL^|FindStr "^[0-9]*_[^_]"')Do @RoboCopy . "%%A" "%%A_%%B" /Mov>NUL 2>&1
FOR /F "eol=| delims=" %%I IN ('dir "???????" /AD-H /B 2^>nul ^| findstr /R /X "......."') DO MOVE /Y "%%I*" "%%I" >nul 2>nul
Exit
:somewhere_else
exit
```

Comment: JlAma, can you please confirm whether you want a simpler method for the code you've stated does what you're looking for, or whether you want something to satisfy the requirements laid out in your question body, _(as they don't match)_.

Comment: @JlAma The most efficient code for the task depends on facts not written in question. How to identify files to move? Have the file names a specific naming scheme like the file name of a file to move starts always with seven digits and an underscore and first character must be `3`? Is it possible that there are files to move for which no directory yet exist? Are there for example 10 target folders and 20.000 files to move (my posted solution is more efficient) or are there 500 folders, but usually only up to 20 files to move on batch file execution (Compo's solution is more efficient)?

Comment: @JlAma Does the source folder with the files to move contain other files which should be never moved and which would require identifying the files to move depending on a specific naming scheme? Does the parent target folder contain subfolders which should be ignored for this task at all? The answers on all those questions must be taken into account for development of most efficient code for this task, i.e. to get done the movements of the files as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a much easier solution in this use case with the target folders all existing already into which the files in the current directory should be moved containing **anywhere** inside the folder name.

```
for /D %%I in (*) do move /Y "*%%I*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

**FOR** searches in current directory for non-hidden directories matching the wildcard pattern `*` (any directory name) and runs the command **MOVE** with source string being a wildcard pattern matching all files containing current directory name anywhere in file name.

The standard output listing the moved files and the total number of moved files is suppressed by redirecting it from **STDOUT** to device **NUL**.

The error message output in case of no file to move exists or one of the files could not be moved (for example on being opened in an application) is redirected from **STDERR** to device **NUL** to suppress it.

This single line can be modified in many ways. For example the directory wildcard pattern can be changed to `????` to process only the directories in the current directory with just one to four characters and ignore the directories with more characters.

```
for /D %%I in (????) do move /Y "*%%I*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

Another variation changes the wildcard pattern for command **MOVE** to move only files containing the folder name between two underscores.

```
for /D %%I in (????) do move /Y "*_%%I_*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

And it would be possible to modify the command line to process always the directories and files in the directory of the batch file instead of current directory.

```
for /D %%I in ("%~dp0????") do move /Y "%~dp0*_%%~nxI_*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

`%~dp0` references drive and path of argument 0 of batch file. Argument 0 of a processed batch file is always the batch file itself. So `%~dp0` references drive and path of batch file which is always ending with a backslash and which is the reason why no additional backslash should be used on concatenating `%~dp0` with file/folder names or wildcard patterns.

Next the folder to search for the target folders and the folder containing the files to move can be modified as well as the source wildcard pattern for command **MOVE** to move only those files containing the current folder name at beginning followed by an underscore.

```
for /D %%I in ("C:\Temp\Folder1\*") do move /Y "C:\Temp\Folder2\%%~nxI_*" "%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

**Update:**

The following command line can be used for processing just the directories in `Folder1` being a subdirectory of the batch file directory with **exactly** seven characters to move the files in the subdirectory `Folder2` of the batch file directory with a file name beginning with the current folder name and an underscore:

```
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0Folder1\???????" /AD-H /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X "......."') do move /Y "%~dp0Folder2\%%%I_*" "%~dp0Folder1\%%I\" >nul 2>nul
```

The command **FOR** runs in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line.

The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded command line with using a separate command process started in background.

In background command process the command **DIR** is executed first with searching for non-hidden directories with one to seven characters and outputting just the matching directory names.

This output is redirected to **FINDSTR** which searches with a regular expression for lines (directory names) having **exactly** seven characters. Only those directory names are output by **FINDSTR** used here as filter for the directory names with less than seven characters.

**FOR** captures this output to handle **STDOUT** of started background command process and processes those lines after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur in this case. It would by default also ignore lines starting with `;`. A directory name can start with a semicolon, but it cannot contain `|`. For that reason `eol=|` redefines end of line character to a vertical bar to not ignore any directory name. The captured line would be also split up on horizontal tabs and normal spaces and just first tab/space separated substring would be assigned to the loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is disabled completely with `delims=` at end of the options string which defines an empty list of string delimiters.

The regular expression search string `.......` can be modified to be even more restrictive like using one of these two strings:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]
```

The directory name must consist of exactly seven of these characters `0123456789¹²³` on using first regular expression search string. That the character range `0-9` includes also `¹²³` is a **FINDSTR** special. No other executable supporting regular expressions do that as far as I know. The second regular expression search string matches only directory names consisting of exactly seven digits.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... for an explanation of `%~dp0`.
- `dir /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `move /?`

See also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Answer (score 0):

As you have failed to answer my question in the comments, here's a single line which should effectively do what the code snippet you provided does:

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1*Delims=_" %%A In ('Where ".:???????_*.*" 2^>NUL^|FindStr "^[0-9]*_[^_]"')Do @RoboCopy . "%%A" "%%A_%%B" /Mov>NUL 2>&1
```

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bat
For /F "EOL=_Tokens=1*Delims=_" %A In ('Where ".:???????_*.*" 2^>NUL^|FindStr "^[0-9]*_[^_]"')Do @RoboCopy . "%A" "%A_%B" /Mov>NUL 2>&1
```

The difference with this is that it'll choose only directories whose first token is seven numeric digits. It will also create the destination directories, if they don't already exist, so it works using the same method as your provided snippet.